# GITHUB clonar proyecto con todas las ramas

Tags: github, git-clone

Necesito clonar un proyecto con las ramas independientes (tal cual esta en GITHUB).
**El problema** es que cuando uso el comando "git clone " **me clona una sola rama con los archivos fusionados de todas las ramas**. O sea no clona el proyecto con las ramas independientes.

Comment: git clone de hecho copia todo el histórico del repositorio remoto. Puedes hacer checkout a las ramas remotas y debería funcionar sin problema. O incluso puedes ir a versiones anteriores de una rama. Todo eso es local, es un sistema de versionamiento distribuido.

Comment: Despues de hacer el git clone si se hace un git branch solo mostrara que existe la rama main (o la original donde esta guardado todo el proyecto) pero al colocar git branch y "el nombre de la rama que deberia existir" aparece y al hacer el proximo git branch aparecera tambien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero clona tu repositorio

```
$ git clone git://example.com/myproject
$ cd myproject
```

observa tus ramas con

```
$ git branch
```

Si tienes muchas ramas remotas puedes hacer:

```
$ pull --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Despues de clonar el proyecto escribe el siguiente comando

```
git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/rama1
  remotes/origin/rama2
  remotes/origin/rama3
  remotes/origin/main
```

Te mostrara todas las ramas de ese repositorio y despues has un checkout por cada rama.

```
git checkout rama1
Switched to branch 'rama1'
```

Tendras las ramas que haces checkout en tu repositorio local

```
git branch
* rama1
  main
```